# Transfer a Django project using Conda environment to a Docker container

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile, conda

I am new to Django and am trying to follow the book Django for Professionals 3.1 by William S. Vincent. In this context, I am trying to move a simple Django project currently on my system (Mac OS) using conda environment on the PyCharm IDE to a Docker container.

### The Problem

The book uses `pipenv` for the project and suggests to enter the following code in the `Dockerfile`:
[image: Dockerfile code given in the book]

However, since I am using a Conda environment for the project, I cannot use the above code in `Dockerfile`.

### What I Tried

##### Step 1

I started by entering the following code to create the `environment.yml` file containing all packages that the project uses.

```
(django_for_professionals_31) My-MacBook-Pro:django_for_professionals_31_ch1 me$ conda env export --no-builds > environment.yml
```

My `environment.yml` file looks like the following*:

```
name: django_for_professionals_31
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - asgiref=3.4.1
  - bzip2=1.0.8
  - ca-certificates=2022.4.26
  - certifi=2022.5.18.1
  - django=3.2.5
  - krb5=1.19.2
  - libedit=3.1.20210910
  - libffi=3.3
  - libpq=12.9
  - ncurses=6.3
  - openssl=1.1.1o
  - pip=21.2.4
  - psycopg2=2.8.6
  - python=3.10.4
  - pytz=2021.3
  - readline=8.1.2
  - setuptools=61.2.0
  - sqlite=3.38.3
  - sqlparse=0.4.1
  - tk=8.6.12
  - typing_extensions=4.1.1
  - tzdata=2022a
  - wheel=0.37.1
  - xz=5.2.5
  - zlib=1.2.12
prefix: /opt/anaconda3/envs/django_for_professionals_31
```

##### Step 2

Then, based on [this tutorial](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/#working), I tried to write my `Dockerfile`, as shown below:

```
# Pull base image
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Create the environment:
COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

# Make RUN commands use the new environment:
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "django_for_professionals_31", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Demonstrate the environment is activated:
RUN echo "Make sure django is installed:"
RUN python -c "import django"

# The code to run when container is started:
COPY run.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "django_for_professionals_31", "python", "run.py"]

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

Thereafter, I ran the command to build a docker image. The command and output I got are given below:

```
(django_for_professionals_31) My-MacBook-Pro:django_for_professionals_31_ch1 me$ docker build .
[+] Building 3.6s (12/13)                                                                                                                               
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 737B                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3:latest                                                                           3.3s
 => [auth] continuumio/miniconda3:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                              0.0s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3@sha256:24103733efebe6d610d868ab16a6f0e5f114c7aad0326a793d946b73af15391d                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 5.29kB                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] WORKDIR /code                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] COPY environment.yml .                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [4/8] RUN conda env create -f environment.yml                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [5/8] RUN echo "Make sure django is installed:"                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [6/8] RUN python -c "import django"                                                                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [7/8] COPY run.py .                                                                                                                      0.0s
------
 > [7/8] COPY run.py .:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/run.py" not found: not found
```

##### Step 3

I was not sure what to do next when I got this error, and my first instinct was to comment out the code under the `# The code to run when container is started:` section in `Dockerfile`. So, I did that and my `Dockerfile` looked like the following:

```
# Pull base image
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Create the environment:
COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

# Make RUN commands use the new environment:
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "django_for_professionals_31", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Demonstrate the environment is activated:
RUN echo "Make sure django is installed:"
RUN python -c "import django"

# The code to run when container is started:
#COPY run.py .
#ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "django_for_professionals_31", "python", "run.py"]

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

Upon re-running the `$ docker build .` on the terminal, I was able to create the Docker image, as the last line of the output I got was  `=> => writing image sha256:...`.

##### Step 4

Then, the book required to create the `docker-compose.yml` file. I am using the exact same code in the book, given below:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

After that, I ran the command to build a Docker container based on the created image. The command and output are shown below.

```
(django_for_professionals_31) My-MacBook-Pro:django_for_professionals_31_ch1 me$ docker-compose up
[+] Building 3.8s (13/13) FINISHED                                                                                                                      
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 734B                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3:latest                                                                           3.4s
 => [auth] continuumio/miniconda3:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                              0.0s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/continuumio/miniconda3@sha256:24103733efebe6d610d868ab16a6f0e5f114c7aad0326a793d946b73af15391d                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 5.11kB                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [2/7] WORKDIR /code                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [3/7] COPY environment.yml .                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [4/7] RUN conda env create -f environment.yml                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [5/7] RUN echo "Make sure django is installed:"                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [6/7] RUN python -c "import django"                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [7/7] COPY . /code/                                                                                                                            0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                            0.1s
 => => writing image sha256:d0166e8db7d10a43f18975955b398d9227ae7c2a217a69a2fe76a9cc869c0917                                                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/django_for_professionals_31_ch1_web                                                                             0.0s
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Network django_for_professionals_31_ch1_default  Created                                                                                        0.1s
 ⠿ Container django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  Created                                                                                        0.2s
Attaching to django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 11, in main
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  | 
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  | 
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  |     main()
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 13, in main
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  |     raise ImportError(
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1  | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
django_for_professionals_31_ch1-web-1 exited with code 1
```

---

From the above, it seems to me that (I could be wrong though) after commenting out the two lines of code in `Dockerfile`, the conda environment does not get activated in the Docker container but including those two lines of code leads to the `failed to compute cache key: "/run.py" not found: not found` error because of which the image cannot be created.

How can I resolve the above issue and create a docker image and use that to build a container for my project? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

---

****Note***: I removed the `libcxx=12.0.0` package from the `environment.yml` file because with it, I got the following error upon running `$ docker build .` on the terminal. I took the advice to remove this package after reading [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6073#issuecomment-356981567)

```
> [4/7] RUN conda env create -f environment.yml:                                                                                                       
#9 1.036 Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done                                                                                
#9 8.859 Solving environment: ...working... failed                                                                                                      
#9 8.874 
#9 8.874 ResolvePackageNotFound: 
#9 8.874   - libcxx=12.0.0
#9 8.874
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

environment.yml

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - asgiref==3.3.1
  - Django==3.1.7
  - pytz==2021.1
  - sqlparse==0.4.1
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3


WORKDIR /app


COPY environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml


SHELL ["conda","run","-n","myenv","/bin/bash","-c"]



COPY . .
#start server inside container
CMD ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output","-n", "myenv", "python3","manage.py", "runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

At the current dir, Build image :

```
docker build --tag python-django .
```

Run the image :

```
docker run --publish 8000:8000 python-django
```